# Why does the sizeof operator give different outputs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning the basics of C for a course I am taking soon, and right now I am learning about pointers and arrays. I have been using a number of references to learn it but in this "Head First into C" book I have, there is the following:

```
char s[] = "How big is it?"
char *t = s;
printf("%i\n", sizeof(s));  /* returns 15 */
printf("%i\n", sizeof(t));  /* returns 4 or 8 */
```

Thats all fine, but if i change the last line to:

```
printf("%i\n", sizeof(*s));  /* returns 1 (on my compy anyway) */
```

So my question is why is this different? Apologizes if it's a really basic thing, but I have yet to wrap my brain around the concept of pointers.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: saying that `sizeof(*s)` reminds you about `t` is something of a non sequitur, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yeah. I thought it was talking about `sizeof(*t)` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(s)` returns the size of the `char` array, `s`, which is 14 `char`s long, plus one for the null terminator; ergo 15 bytes.

`sizeof(t)` returns the size of the `char` pointer `t`. `t` isn't aware of `s`'s length, because when you assign its value from `s`, `s` decays from an array type to a pointer type, losing the length information in the process. As you have discovered, pointers can vary in size depending on the target platform.

`sizeof(*s)` and `sizeof(*t)` both dereference the address of the first `char` in the array, yielding a single `char`. `sizeof(char)` == 1, because a `char` is per definitionem a single byte.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Quare Latinum? ;)

Comment: Because it looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

One is the size of an array and the other is the size of a pointer.

Arrays and pointer are different types in C although there are implicit conversion rules between arrays and pointers..

The size of an array initialized by a character string literal is the number of characters of the string + 1 for the null terminator.

The size of a pointer to `char` (i.e., `char *`) is an implementation defined size of an object large enough to hold the pointer value.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
printf("%i\n", sizeof(s));  /* returns 15 */
```

outputs the number of bytes that that array s occupies.

This statement

```
printf("%i\n", sizeof(t));  /* returns 4 or 8 */
```

displays the number of byte occupied by pointer t. Usually pointers have size either 4 or 8 bytes depending of using system.

This statement

```
printf("%i\n", sizeof(*s));  /* returns 1 (on my compy anyway) */
```

displays sizeof `char` because expression `*s` has type char. In all system size of an object of type char is equal to 1.